# Django math question

Tags: python, django

I have the following code in my template:

```
{{ object.rating.get_percent|floatformat|add:"-100" }}
```

Which outputs `-50`

The value of `object.rating.get_percent` is `50`. I want to subtract it from the number `100`. So I am expecting `50` in return. Why do I get `-50`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get -50 because "-100" is the *second* operand to `add`. The first operand is the result of `object.rating.get_percent|floatformat`.

Essentially your expression is:

```
50 + -100
```

If you're really desperate to calculate "100 - x", you can use the [`{% widthratio %}` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#widthratio):

```
{% widthratio -100|add:object.rating.get_percent -100 100 %}
```

However, you should really just get the backend developers to add a template filter for you.

Comment: that's what I thought, so do you know how I can get 50? I looked at the django docs and the only math template filter they have is add. I only have access to the front end template tags/variables so I can't do it in the python.

Comment: So if `object.rating.get_percent` is 60, you want the output to be 40?

Comment: @Sam Have a look at my example using `widthratio`, it might be what you're after.